# How to manually call check_test in Django BooleanField

Tags: python, django

Given the following in models.py:

```
class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    samplefield = forms.BooleanField(initial=True, required=True)
```

If, in my view, I enter `{{ form.samplefield }}`, everything generates as expected.

However, if I want to break it out and get more granular with the field, I can't seem to work `check_test` the way I would expect. This doesn't work:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ form.samplefield.name }}" id="{{ form.samplefield.id_for_label }}"{% if form.samplefield.check_test %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: @PauloBu Nothing happens. No error, it just doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

`check_test` is a method for the `CheckboxInput` widget. I think the correct way to check if the field is checked would be:

```
{% if form.samplefield %} checked="checked"{% endif %}
```

By the way, reading the [docs for BooleanField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield) seems your `samplefield` field validation can only pass if the field is checked:

> Since all Field subclasses have `required=True` by default, the validation condition here is important. If you want to include a boolean in your form that can be either True or False (e.g. a checked or unchecked checkbox), you must remember to pass in `required=False` when creating the `BooleanField`.

Comment: That just checks if the field exists, I think. If I set `initial` to `False`, `{% if form.samplefield %}` will still respond as true.